# Email External Domain. Error: The server response was: Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I am able to use the code similar to the one below to send email to internal and external domain on my localhost. However, when I deploy on the server, it gets the error "The server response was: Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable". What does this mean and how can I correct this?

```
SmtpClient serv = new SmtpClient();
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add("test@domain.com);
msg.Body = "body";
msg.Subject = "subj";
msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
msg.IsBodyHtml = isHTML;
serv.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
serv.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpServerUserName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpServerPassword"]);
 serv.Send(msg);
```

I have looked at similar questions and most suggest that this is due to wrong addresses. But this is not my case as I am able to send it on my local machine. My hosting server has Windows 7 and IIS 7.5.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: FYI, both the `SmtpClient` and `MailMessage` need to be in `using` blocks: `using (SmtpClient serv = new SmtpClient()) { using (MailMessage msg = new MailMessage()) { /* code */ }}`